# NameError when using `eval` in closure

Tags: python

Consider the following code

```py
a = 1
fn = eval('lambda: a')
fn()
```

it will work well.
But if I move the above code into a closure

```py
def x():
  a = 1
  fn = eval('lambda: a')
  fn()
x()
```

Then I will get:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

It looks like variables define in closure are treated differently. Then I try to apply `global` to `a` and it works well again.

```py
def x():
  global a
  a = 1
  fn = eval('lambda: a')
  fn()
x()
```

Though it works now but it will introduce other issue in my code, so `global` is not acceptable. Are there any other solutions to solve this issue. And it will be appreciated to explain me the reason.

### Update

```py
def x():
  a = 1
  fn = eval('lambda: a', locals())
  fn()
x()
```

That works. But I still wondering why it is different in closure.

Comment: `eval` has `locals` and `globals` parameters that you can use to set the namespace that will be used. Also, ya, `eval` is *significantly* worse than `global`.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)? *"`eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)` ... If the locals dictionary is omitted it defaults to the globals dictionary."*

Comment: `eval` is used to accept lambda expression that provided by user as string in there configuration file. It's a computational software, so that's OK. https://github.com/chenggroup/ai2-kit/blob/main/ai2_kit/domain/selector.py#L263
  And global is because this variable will be used in multiple  async task, so it must be local.

Comment: I have try `eval('lambda: a", locals=locals())` and it raise error that `eval` takes no keyword arguments.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It has nothing to do with  global vs eval.  I am using eval because I need to handle the filter expression string passing by user in a yaml file.

Comment: Try `eval('lambda: a', None, locals())`. The documentation is a bit misleading as @wjandrea pointed out here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100546